# How to add pre and post code to a method with Groovy meta programming?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

**Question**

There is a class `MyClass` with a method `myMethod()`. How can I add some code, for example `println "hello"`, that is executed every time before `myMethod()` is called?

**Example of method replacement**

I know that an entire method can be replaced like this.

```
MyClass.metaClass.myMethod = { -> println "myMethod() has been replaced..." }
```

However, I don't want to replace the entire method. I just want to add some code before and after the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing:

```
class MyClass {
  String name

  String expand() {
    "expanded $name"
  }
}

// Cache the old expand method
def oldExpand = MyClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod( 'expand', null )

// Create a new one
MyClass.metaClass.expand = { -> 
  // Do something
  println "Pre stuff"
  try {
    // then invoke and return the original method
    oldExpand.invoke( delegate )
  }
  finally {
    // finally doing something else
    println "Post stuff"
  }
}

def a = new MyClass( name:'tim' )

println "received: " + a.expand()
```